# ClipboardManager does not work on Android Q. Is there any workaround?

Tags: java, android

Android Q blocks background clipboard access. Is there any way I can use this service in my app? Is there any permission to enable this function?

Comment: "Is there any permission to enable this function?" -- I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

Google has restricted access to clipboard data as previously rumored.

I saw `android.Manifest.permission.READ_CLIPBOARD_IN_BACKGROUND` permission in `ClipboardService.java` from `com.android.server.clipboard` package.

But I couldn't use it and my compile sdk version is 29. Maybe we can use it in the next sdk version.